# Colorbox close button reacts different from clicking on overlay

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i have a page with a few elements, which open and close on a click (slideToggle on a class)

In these elements i have images on which you can click (via Colorbox) so you get a blown up version of the image on an overlay (basic Colorbox install does this).

The blown up version has an X-icon (in the bottom right corner of the image) on which you can click to close the image. You can also click on the overlay, which also closes the image.

Funny thing is that when you click on the X-icon, the elements will not slideToggle anymore. If you click on the overlay, slideToggle on these elements still works.

Now my question, how can i get the X-icon to work the same? So that when clicking the X-icon the slideToggle still works, as like clicking the overlay?

I'm absolutely not a jQuery expert, perhaps time to become more known in the jQuery world, but is there anybody who had the same issue or knows how to solve this?

Comment: please add some code for us to have a look at, its hard to solve a problem with nothing to go on. You could maybe create a fiddle on http://www.jsfiddle.net, but there is a code snippet provided.

Comment: you can get colorbox free on the net. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/